# Как можно вывести данные заказа WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Как передать другие данные заказа телеграма, какой метод можно использовать?
Пытался передать $total (стоимость товаров), но оно не выводится.

Спасибо!

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_new_order', 'new_order_send_tg',  1, 1  );
function new_order_send_tg( $order_id ) {
$order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
$total = $order->get_formatted_order_total();
$msg = '*Заявка*';

$msg .= 'Новый заказ: '.$order_id;

$msg .= 'Стоимость '.$total;



$userId = 'xxx'; // Ваш id в телеграм
$token = 'xxxx'; // Token бота

file_get_contents('https://api.telegram.org/bot'. $token .'/sendMessage?chat_id='. $userId .'&text=' . urlencode($msg) . '&parse_mode=markdown'); // Отправляем сообщение
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$firstname = $order->get_billing_first_name();
```

Вот таким образом можно передавать детали заказа, я разобрался